# How to realise a 'sequence diagram' without using uml sequence diagram metamodel

Tags: metamodel, eclipse-sirius

I'm working on a description of a scenario by using sequence diagram. and i would like to define the metamodel without having all the uml element for the SD. Kind of creation of my own SD. the problem is i don't know the steps to follow. does anybody know how i should start?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you checked the documentation found at: https://www.eclipse.org/sirius/doc/specifier/sequences/Sequence%20Diagrams.html

Comment: by the way i would like to add some Duration Constraints but the UML_Designer documentation and SiriusSequenceSpecification do not help me that much. any idea how to do it?

Comment: It does not seem to be supported in Sirius. I see several possibilities: if you have the time and and resources, you can probably contribute it to Sirius since it is open source. If you don't, it depends if you only need these constraints only for the diagrams, or if you are going to exploit it semantically (e.g. by loading the model to do something with it like generating code or documentation, etc.). If you only need it graphically, you can probably make a look-alike with GMF notes (in the palette "note" or something like that).